# Managing large number of rules - Drools

Tags: java, drools

We have a business rules system being planned and we have chosen JBoss Drools to begin testing our use cases. We have planned to structure the DRL files as follows:

```
Global.drl
     Company1.drl
          Company1/Team1.drl
          Company1/Team2.drl
          ...
          Company1/TeamN.drl             
     Company2.drl
     ...
     CompanyN.drl
```

This structuring will help us to identify what rules to run for different classes of business objects.

Now the problem is:

1. How to know whether there is a similar/conflicting rule already present in a system of large number of rules.  When the rules system grows, does adding the new rule requires the developer to scan through all the rules manually to verify the conflicting rules, before writing new rule?
2. How to correctly order the rules (using salience) in such a large rules system?
3. Is there a way to quickly list rules of a particular category, which will help us to know the existing rules that are similar before adding new rule.

Thanks

Comment: the rules express a business fact. how should drools determine whether the business facts contradict each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers:

> 1. How to know whether there is a similar/conflicting rule already present in a system of large number of rules. When the rules system
>      grows, does adding the new rule requires the developer to scan through
>      all the rules manually to verify the conflicting rules, before writing
>      new rule?

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this. I've found that the best way to keep a coherent rule base is to have an extensive set of tests to validate as many scenarios as possible.

> 2. How to correctly order the rules (using salience) in such a large rules system?

Good practices tell us that is usually not a good idea to establish an order in the execution of the rules. The rules themselves should be done in a way that they are as independent of the execution of other rules as possible. There are of course situations where you need to set a specific order. In those situations, Drools provides some ways to achieve this:

- [salience](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_rule_attributes): it allows you to specify the **EXECUTION** order of the rules.
- [agenda-group](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_rule_attributes): it allows you to group rules into logical groups and to only **EXECUTE** the rules in a specific group. You can chain the execution of these groups.

> 3. Is there a way to quickly list rules of a particular category, which will help us to know the existing rules that are similar before adding new rule.

Not sure what you mean by *category*, but I guess the answer is no.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I agree that there is no out of box ways in Drools to attain this. Thanks